# Настройка asp.net-проекта в Visual Studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Всем добрый День.
Столкнулся с с небольшой проблемой.
Создаю в **Visual Studio 2010 MVC 3** проект, затем в студии захожу *Project -> ASP.NET Configuration*, и при попытке зайти во вкладку **Security**, выдаёт ошибку:

> There is a problem with your selected
> data store. This can be caused by an
> invalid server name or credentials, or
> by insufficient permission. It can
> also be caused by the role manager
> feature not being enabled. Click the
> button below to be redirected to a
> page where you can choose a new data
> store.
>
> The following message may help in
> diagnosing the problem: Не удалось
> сформировать пользовательский
> экземпляр SQL Server из-за ошибки при
> запуске процесса для экземпляра
> пользователя. Соединение будет
> закрыто.

Если зайти во вкладку: **Provider** и нажать на ссылку: **Select a single provider for all site management data**, там жму на кнопку **TEST** на против "**AspNetSqlProvider**", и там уже выдаёт ошибку:

> Could not establish a connection to
> the database.   If you have not yet
> created the SQL Server database, exit
> the Web Site Administration tool, use
> the aspnet_regsql command-line utility
> to create and configure the database,
> and then return to this tool to set
> the provider.

**Собственно вопрос:** Как и что сделать, чтобы всё это исправить? *Желательно более подробно, если не сложно. Спасибо. :)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно стоит попробовать заюзать aspnet_regsql, как предлагается в описании второй ошибки и создать/сконфигурировать необходимую бд. Подробная инструкция [тут](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms229862(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Ну я воспользовался инструкцией, по ссылке. Но что - то ни к чему не привело.  
И на всякий случай, в добавок напишу, что если в проекте в папку App_Data попытаться добавить файл Базы Данных *.mdf, то студия выдаёт ошибку:  
http://cs11209.vkontakte.ru/u7429599/140172200/x_837fbc73.jpg

Comment: Попробуйте удалить все по этому пути:
C:\Documents and Settings\[user]\ASPNET\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Большое спасибо. Удаление всех файлов помогло. :)  
Не знаю, как тут пометить, что этот ответ был правильным.

Comment: Рядом с первым моим ответом нарисованы две руки одна вверх другая вниз. По идее под ними должно быть что-то типа принять ответ, либо нужно просто нажать на руку, которая показывает вверх.